# How do I connect a model instance to a user in django?

Tags: python, django

Im looking to make it so the logged in user that creates a profile is linked to their guestprofile model when they create their profile.

When I create the guest profile while logged in, it successfully creates the guest profile, but **in the guest profile admin screen there is no user connected to the guest profile model created**.  **Instead there is a dropdown menu listing all users**, which makes the connection process manual.  Thanks.

Forms.py

```
class AddProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length=50, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    location = forms.CharField(max_length=100, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    summary = forms.CharField(max_length=500, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
    profile_pic = forms.ImageField()
    

class Meta:
    model = GuestProfile
    fields = ('name', 'location', 'summary', 'profile_pic')
```

Models.py

```
class GuestProfile(models.Model):

user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
location = models.CharField(max_length=100)
summary = models.TextField(max_length=350)
profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="images/")


def __str__(self):
    return str(self.user)
```

views.py

```
class AddProfileView(CreateView):

    model = GuestProfile
    form_class = AddProfileForm
    template_name = 'profilemanip/addprofile.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('home')

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user
```

**Edit: I ended up solving my issue by changing my AddProfileView to the following:**

```
def AddProfileView(request,*args,**kwargs):
form = AddProfileForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():

    obj = form.save(commit=False)

    obj.user = request.user
    obj.save()

    form = AddProfileForm()

return render(request, "profilemanip/addprofile.html", {"form": form})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your AddProfileForm in order to associate the user with the profile:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.user = kwargs.pop('user',None)
        super(AddProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: After adding that snippet I receive the following error.  AttributeError at /accounts/create_profile/
type object 'Meta' has no attribute 'required'.  Tomorrow Ill work on sorting out the error.

Comment: I removed the two last lines. They aren't needed.